# What is difference between Laravel `app` method and `new` keyword?

Tags: laravel, oop

I found that some developer use `app(SomeService::class);` while other use `new SomeService();` in Laravel? Is there any difference between them?

Comment: Just dumping thoughts: one of the great things of PHP is that you can actually check all the source code of all the packages you include. Search for the `app()` method within the Laravel package and you can see its inner workings there.

Comment: Others have already mentioned it, but I think the keyword here is "dependency injection". My suggestion would be to learn about this pattern first. Seems like a good starting read: http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the main difference is the `ServiceContainer`.

If you instantiate using `app(YourService::class)`, the `ServiceContainer` will use `reflection` to inject in the class `constructor` the dependecies required.

So you don't have to explicit `use` all the dependencies needed.

It's well explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container).

Answer (score 4):

Please check https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/providers.

Briefly speaking if you want to customize the class which you will use in runtime you can change it in provider (make it singleton or pass some arguments) and get in runtime via `$app` (if you have no opportunity to use `DI`). but when you making object vie `new` its only creates an instance.

Imagine that we have class `A` which receive 2 config parameters in construction.

So you need everywhere call   `new A($param1,$param2)` . but using providers u can use `DI` to get instance of class A with already passed parameters or `$app` if u have no opportunity to use `DI`